# List collision not working

Tags: python, list, pygame, collision

I am currently using a list to spawn in the enemies running across the screen and wanted to know what I am doing wrong in my code. I want the basketball to collide with the badlist. When I run there are no errors, the basketball just doesn't collide with the badlist.

```
death = pygame.Rect.collidelist(badlist, basketball)
if death:
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 50)
    textsurface = myfont.render('The Baddies got you', True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(textsurface,(700,700))
```

Comment: First of all, you didn't say what is not working

Comment: How does the actual result differ from what you expected?

Comment: Or what your code has anything to do with the prose.

Answer (score 3):

First, you have to call [`collidelist`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelist) on a `Rect` instance, not on the `Rect` type itself.<sup>1</sup>

Assuming `basketball` is a `Rect`, and `badlist` is a list of `Rect`s, and you're trying to see whether `basketball` collides with any of the rectangles in `badlist`:

```
death = basketball.collidelist(badlist)
```

Second, `collidelist` doesn't return a boolean value telling you whether there was a collision or not, it returns the index of the first collision. That index will be falsey—that is, zero—if the basketball collides with the first rectangle, but truthy—that is, nonzero—if it collides with any of the other rectangles, or with none at all. So, what you actually want to check is:

```
death = basketball.collidelist(badlist) != -1
```

Finally:

```
pygame.font.init() # you have to call this at the start, 
# if you want to use this module.
```

You actually put a comment here explaining what's wrong with this line. You have to call this at the start of your program, not each time you want to load a font.

---

<sub>1. The reason you're not getting an immediate `TypeError` that tells you this is that technically, what you're doing isn't illegal, it's a call to the "unbound method". You can call a method directly on the class, but then you have to pass the instance—the `self` you want to call the method on—as the first argument. So, `Rect.collidelist(basketball, badlist)` would actually do the same thing as `basketball.collidelist(badlist)`. But you got the arguments backward, so instead of asking it to check every rect in `badlist` to see which one collides `basketball`, you're asking it to check every rect in `basketball` to see which one collides `badlist`—and that's nonsense, but maybe not nonsense that Python or PyGame tests for.</sub>

Comment: The ball is a rect and the list is a list of rects. When I run the program using your advice, "AttributeError: 'Ball' object has no attribute 'collidelist'" pops up, wanted to know if you knew how to fix it.

Comment: @MaxCOSSETTO According to that error message, the ball isn’t a `Rect`, it’s a `Ball`.

Comment: could that be from a mask? Because I am using mask collisions.